# Moveit! and URDF problem

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Dear Community!
I have a problem that I can't resolve during already a few days. I have created simple test robot arm in SolidWorks. I followed instructions on setting the axis correctly for all joints (X-forward, Z-up). I have exported URDF model from SolidWorks. I have created Moveit! config for this URDF model with Moveit! wizard.
Models successfully loads into rviz. I can control it with robot_state_publisher GUI panel.
**But I can't set the Goal State with Interactive Marker either with the code.** I always get  "Fail: ABORTED: No motion plan found. No execution attempted.".
I have uploaded to GoogleDrive two tars:

1. **drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx529USSkqSbd0k0djE0aEVKYTg/edit?usp=sharing** (model exported from SolidWorks: URDF, meshes)
2. **drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx529USSkqSbbGRjckp5bVRNbjQ/edit?usp=sharing**
   (generated Moveit! config)

Could you please be so kind and review this packages, and tell me what I'm doing wrong!
I really need help with this!

Great thanks ahead!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/97661/moveit!-and-urdf-problem/) by [maska](https://answers.ros.org/users/7951/maska/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2013-11-04

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [maska](https://answers.ros.org/users/7951/maska/) on 2013-11-04**:
An arm for Moveit! shall be strictly 6DOF? Or could have less DOF?

**Comment by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on 2013-11-04**:
Try to set the logger levels of move_arm and ompl_ros to DEBUG using rxconsole. That could give some extra debug info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have set the
position_only_ik: True
in kinematics.yaml file and this has solved the problem.

---

Originally posted by [maska](https://answers.ros.org/users/7951/maska/) with karma: 61 on 2013-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [maska](https://answers.ros.org/users/7951/maska/) on 2013-11-06**:
How to mark the question as resolved?

**Comment by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on 2013-11-06**:
Click the v button